# Is there wrong with using absolute layout

Tags: android, layout

Error shown like absolute layout is depreciated. I can't understand whats wrong with using this layout

```
<AbsoluteLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="0px"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slideimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="420dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`depreciated` meaning that it is old and now It is replaced with new methods.

You should not use Absolute layout unless you are developing for a particular screen device only.

Comment: Thaq. But which layout should be used to get same effect of absolute layout

Comment: @user3096252 The replacement for `AbsoluteLayout` is `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I would consider `FrameLayout` to be a very poor replacement for the `AbsoluteLayout`. Is that actually mentioned somewhere in the docs? A `FrameLayout` is for stacking views and gives you little control over their placement, while the `AbsoluteLayout` lets you position the views at will.